# Finding convergence rate for Bisection, Newton, Secant Methods?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

I have implemented the bisection, Newton, and secant methods for solving nonlinear equations in one dimension. I know my methods work to find at least one root, however how would I go about solving for the convergence rate for each method? For example if my nonlinear equation is $x^3 - 2x - 5 = 0$ and I use the bisection method, I get a root of $2.09455$, however I am not sure how I can use this to find the convergence rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence rate connects the error in one step with the error in another step by
$$|x_{n+1} - x| \leqslant c |x_{n} - x|^p$$

So if $$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|^p}>0$$
you have convergence of order $p$.

Since you usually don't know the exact solution you can use the following formula:

$$ p\approx \frac{\log|\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_n-x_{n-1}}|}{\log|\frac{x_{n}-x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}}|}$$

You should expect results around $1$ for the bisection method, increasing convergence up to $1.6$ for the secant method and increasing convergence up to $2$ for Newton's method.

Comment: So would I solve for p in each iteration of my loop where I am calculating $x_{n+1}$ or once I finish the final iteration of the my loop?

Comment: You can do that while calculating or afterwards. It is independent of the original algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The methods are said to converge with order $p$ if 
$$
e_{i+1} =c e_i^p,
$$
where $e_i = |x_i - x^*|$ is the error in the approximation at the $i$th iteration, $x^*$ is the true root and $x_i$ is the approximation. Here, $c$ and $p$ are constants independent of $i$.

Thus, to measure the rate of convergence we need to store the error in the approximation at each iteration. Note that
$$
\log{e_{i+1}} = \log{c} + p \log{e_i},
$$
i.e. plotting $\log{e_{i+1}}$ against $\log{e_i}$ should (asymptotically) result in a straight line with gradient $p$, which can be measured.

Alternatively, note that
$$
\frac{e_{i+1}}{e_i} = \frac{ce_i^p}{ce_{i-1}^p} = \left(\frac{e_{i}}{e_{i-1}}\right)^p
$$
such that
$$
p = \log{\left( \frac{e_{i+1}}{e_i} \right)} \Big/ \log{\left( \frac{e_{i}}{e_{i-1}} \right)},
$$
which is easily calculated from the errors of three consecutive iterations.

Note that the convergence rate may differ for different functions. In particular, functions with double roots (e.g. $(x-1)^2$) tend to give slower convergence that simple roots. Other functions may show superconvergence for some functions (e.g. $\sin{x}$ near $x=0$ for Newton's method). It may be worth trying your code on a few different examples before you draw conclusions about your methods.

Comment: So where in my code should I be calculating p since I don't know what the real root is how could I get a value of $e_i$?

Comment: Just try it out on functions where you know the roots. I suppose that you have a loop in your code calculating the approximate root at each iteration. That loop is the place to introduce an error calculation.